# go back to initial state when unclick checkbox

Tags: javascript, if-statement, checkbox, click, toggle

I have:

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="all"> text</label>
 <label><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks"> text</label>

const all = document.getElementsByName('all')[0];
const jsFrameworks = document.getElementsByName('js-frameworks')[0];

this.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (all.checked) {
    jsFrameworks.parentNode.className = 'readonly';
    } 
});
```

I thought that when I deselect the checkbox the class 'readonly' will be removed as the code executes only when I tick the checkbox giving the if condition is true. I can't seem to escape the if condition, so to kind of toggle between the click and unclick. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: try to use even listener `click` instead of `change`.... `change` is more accurate for `text` fields...

Comment: @Bloomberg58 Change and click are effectively equivalent for checkboxes, since clicking on it always changes it.

Comment: Why do you think the class will be removed? Not adding something is not the same thing as removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Change it this way:

```
this.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (all.checked) {
    jsFrameworks.parentNode.className = 'readonly';
  } else {
    jsFrameworks.parentNode.className = '';
  }
});
```

This way you are removing the class when unchecked.

UPDATE:

Or you could save the classes that your element may have before:

```
let classesBefore = jsFrameworks.parentNode.className;
this.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (all.checked) {
    jsFrameworks.parentNode.className = classesBefore + ' readonly';
  } else {
    jsFrameworks.parentNode.className = classesBefore;
  }
});
```

Comment: While this works for this situation, It should be noted that this will remove any other classes that may be on the parentNode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const all = document.getElementsByName("all")[0];
const jsFrameworks = document.getElementsByName("js-frameworks")[0];

this.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (all.checked) {
    jsFrameworks.parentNode.classList.add("readonly");
  } else if (!all.checked) {
    jsFrameworks.parentNode.classList.remove("readonly");    
  }
});
```

Comment: Why should he try this? Explain what the problem was and how you fixed it.

Comment: You should just use `else`, since `!all.checked` is the only other possibility.

Comment: @Barmar, It works as I tested it.  In answer to your second question I explicity state !all.checked as I am bulletproofing the else as I may not be aware other possible outcomes.. Sound reasonable?

Comment: What other possibilities are there besides true and false?

Comment: Do you do this with all your `if/else` statements?

Comment: I also used else and just changed the code to be executed but I wished I didn't even use else...I would have imagined the fact that you are deselecting the checkbox will cancel the if statement so the function would be called only on check. I want to understand why it doesn't work this way and you need and else statement even if you deselect the checkbox @Barmar.

Comment: @lovefashro Cancelling the `addClass` doesn't remove a class that was already added earlier.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
this.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentNode.toggle('readonly');
}
```

Comment: I tried classList.toggle() but it removes the class each time I select the checkbox where I want to remove the class when I deselect it. Merunas solution works the best although I was looking for a more efficient way of doing it rather than using else

Comment: `toggle()` is a jQuery function, and it's for hiding and showing an element; `toggleClass()` is for changing a class. But he's not using jQuery.